# Filter with Multiple String Values

Tags: c#, arrays, parameters, rdlc

I need to pass an array of string (product id) values as parameters but it is not available in RDLC Parameters. I am not sure how to get my results without passing the array parameter.

Example :

```
Product ID | Name | Stock
-------------------------
ABC0000001 | Name1 | 50
ABC0000002 | Name2 | 60
ABC0000003 | Name3 | 15
ABC0000004 | Name4 | 50
ABC0000005 | Name5 | 60
ABC0000006 | Name6 | 15
```

Above is the report that returns all data. I need to give client the option to pick specific IDs, generate the report and save as pdf/excel/etc..

Is there a way to achieve this without parameters? Or how can I pass an array of strings as a parameter?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks. Any Solution for the Question ??

Comment: You need to pre-filter data before passing dataset to the report.